Pandas - convert colums to rows in multiindex dataframe
How can I convert the following pandas dataframe:
                dw1 dw2
db_c    c_dat   a   e
        c_idx   b   f
db_s    s_dat   c   g
        s_idx   d   h

to this:
db_c    c_dat   dw1     a
        c_dat   dw2     e
        c_idx   dw1     b
        c_idx   dw2     f
db_s    s_dat   dw1     c
        s_dat   dw2     g
        s_idx   dw1     d
        s_idx   dw2     h

The count of the columns in the first dataframe is variable.

You need to stack as Series, the columns will automatically form a new index level:
out = df.stack()

Output:
db_c  c_dat  dw1    a
             dw2    e
      c_idx  dw1    b
             dw2    f
db_s  s_dat  dw1    c
             dw2    g
      s_idx  dw1    d
             dw2    h
dtype: object

If you want a DataFrame as output, further reset_index:
out = df.stack().to_frame(name='col')

               col
db_c c_dat dw1   a
           dw2   e
     c_idx dw1   b
           dw2   f
db_s s_dat dw1   c
           dw2   g
     s_idx dw1   d
           dw2   h


import pandas as pd


data = {
    ('db_c', 'c_dat'): ['a', 'e'],
    ('db_c', 'c_idx'): ['b', 'f'],
    ('db_s', 's_dat'): ['c', 'g'],
    ('db_s', 's_idx'): ['d', 'h']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['dw1', 'dw2']).T

'''
           dw1 dw2
db_c c_dat   a   e
     c_idx   b   f
db_s s_dat   c   g
     s_idx   d   h
'''

df.index.names = ['db', 'type']
'''
           dw1 dw2
db   type         
db_c c_dat   a   e
     c_idx   b   f
db_s s_dat   c   g
     s_idx   d   h
'''

df_stacked = df.stack().reset_index()
df_stacked.columns = ['db', 'type', 'dw', 'value']
print(df_stacked)
'''

     db   type   dw value
0  db_c  c_dat  dw1     a
1  db_c  c_dat  dw2     e
2  db_c  c_idx  dw1     b
3  db_c  c_idx  dw2     f
4  db_s  s_dat  dw1     c
5  db_s  s_dat  dw2     g
6  db_s  s_idx  dw1     d
7  db_s  s_idx  dw2     h
'''
df_final = df_stacked.set_index(['db', 'type', 'dw'])
print(df_final)
'''
              value
db   type  dw       
db_c c_dat dw1     a
           dw2     e
     c_idx dw1     b
           dw2     f
db_s s_dat dw1     c
           dw2     g
     s_idx dw1     d
           dw2     h
'''

